# Can we edit PV on runtime in EKS to map it to a different EBS volume?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-statefulset

**Use case**

I want to restore data in my statefulset. So, lets say I have got the snapshot and restored the EBS volume. Now I want my pv object to point to the new EBS volume so that my pod can consume to the restored data. How can I do that ?

**Challenges**

1. Restored volume is not attached to EKS instances.
2. I am unable to edit the existing pv object on the fly.

Comment: Did you try `kubectl edit pv <pv-name>` or `kubectl patch` it ? What errors do you get ? How did you define your original volume ? Was it created manually or provisioned automatically based on a `PVC` ?

Comment: @mario I tried `kubectl edit pv <pv-name>` to change the volume id to my restored volume. I got permission denied.

Comment: Apparently it is not allowed. Did you try to get yaml output of your `PV` object i.e. `kubectl get pv <pv-name> -o yaml > my-pv.yaml`, then edit it and `kubectl apply -f my-pv.yaml` again ?